# Animating Windows Store App -UI

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, windows-store-apps

I'm having a hard time figuring out the right way to animate my UI. I know how I could do these two things, but all the solutions I've come up with mean a lot of (ugly) code and there must be a better way.

What would be the correct or the most 'cleanest' way to animate some value, that's bind to a property. I have Color -property on my model, that defines the background color of an element. When that color changes, I would like it to be smooth instead of just sudden color change. Could this be done in xaml, so that model wouldn't have to be aware of that?

How about crossfading? Currently I've achieved this by placing two controls on top of each other (in grid). When I start the change, I 
1. Set visibility of element1 to visible
2. Start animation, that changes opacity of element1 from 0 to 1
3. Start animation, that changes opacity of element2 from 1 to 0
4. When animations have finished, set visibility of element2 to collapsed (so that it won't capture all mouse events)

Oh, and (MVVM)application is written with C# and XAML, using WinRT-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize this is very late, but for those that see this in the future:

You should check out VisualStates and VisualTransitions. They allow you to determine the states that you want to display (such as Opacity of 0 or 1), and the animations that are called when you transition from one state to the next. It's pretty simple to do and can be done almost exclusively in XAML (except calling `GoToState`). You may want to check out some extensions though, as they provide things like Behaviors which allow you to trigger states on things like data changes.

There is a guide for the basic VisualState/VisualTransision [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj819808.aspx).